# jbutton as method actionlistener doesnt work

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

so I created JButton as a method like this

```
    private JButton loginButton() {
        JButton button = new JButton("Login");
        button.setFocusable(false);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setFont(new Font("MV Boli", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        return button;
    }
```

when I try to test if the action listener works, it does nothing. Is this the wrong way how to create JButton and that's why it doesn't wrong or there is something wrong with my code?

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == loginButton()) {
            System.out.println("Test");
        }
    }
```

```
        this.setContentPane(mainPanel());
    }

    private JPanel mainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(loginButton(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        return panel;
    }
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `loginButton()` is creating a new button each time it is called. So, when you have

```
panel.add(loginButton(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

in your `mainPanel()` method, you create the first button. But when you have

```
if (e.getSource() == loginButton())
```

in your `actionPerformed()` method you create a **second** button, which is **different** from the first one you created earlier. That's why your code will not enter the `if()` block.

Comment: One more thing is it good practice to create components like this, by methods that contain the body of the component. Usually, I write components differently but once I read that it's good practice.

Comment: You can write your code as you like, including helper methods that create buttons.